# Why is my neural network not working?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

**background**

I have created a neural network that can be of n inputs, n hidden layers of n length, n outputs. When using it for handwriting recognition - using the Kaggle dataset (a 76mb text file of 28x28 matrix of 0-255 values for hand written numbers), the results are showing that somewhere, something must be wrong. In this case, i am using 784 inputs (each pixel 28x28), 1 hidden layer of 15 neurons, and an output layer of 10 neurons.

Output guesses are a vector like this [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0] - which would mean its guessing a 3. This is based on this http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html#a_simple_network_to_classify_handwritten_digits
(same principals and set up)

I am assuming my problem is somewhere within the back propagation - and because my program has a completely flexible network size in all dimensions (layers, length of layers, etc), my algorithm for back propagating is quite complex - and based on the chain rule explained here https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/
Where essentially, the total error for each output is calculated with respect to each weight, and for hidden layers, the sum of the weight changes in previous layers are used.

when using a learning rate of 0.5, e_total starts at 2.252 and within a minute gets to 0.4462, and then within 5 mins gets no lower than 0.2.

This makes me think somethings must be working. But, when i output the desired outputs and the output guesses, they rarely match, even after 5 mins of iteraton/learning. I would hope to see results like this

```
output layer: [0.05226,0.0262,0.03262,0.0002, 0.1352, 0.99935, 0.00, etc]
output desired: [0,0,0,0,0,1,0, etc]
```

(all < 0.1 except the correct guess value should be > 0.9)

but instead i get things like

```
output layer: [0.15826,0.0262,0.33262,0.0002, 0.1352, 0.0635, 0.00, etc]
output desired: [0,1,0,0,0,0,0, etc]
```

(all < 0.1, so no clear classification, let alone an accurate one.)

I even added a line of code to output 'correct' when the guess value and desired value match - and even though, as i said, the e_total decreases, 'correct' was always happening about 1 in 10 times - which is no better than random!

I have tried different hidden layer lengths, different all sorts of different learning rates - but no good.

**I've given more information in comments which may help**

**UPDATE:**

As recommend, I have used my system to try and learn XOR function - with 2 inputs, 1 hidden layer of 2 neurons, and 1 output. 
meaning, the `desired_list` is now a single element array, either [1] or [0]. Output values seem to be random >0.5 and < 0.7, with no clear relation to desired output. Just to confirm, I have manually tested my feed forward and back prop many times, and they defiantly work how explained in tutorials i've linked.

Comment: When I was debugging my neural net code, I simply built some simple examples and performed the computations by hand, then compared them with the results given by the code. Tedious, but it worked ;)

Comment: debugging a neural network is a nightmare! I have tried doing exactly that - and as far as i can tell, it does work. So i worry i am doing something conceptually wrong

Comment: Good luck getting an answer.  I'll check back and see what kind of feedback you get.

Comment: thank you - ill be very impressed if someone manages to answer this one!

Comment: did you try modifying the learning rate? I wouldn't be surprised if 0.5 is way too high, and would expect something like 0.01 or 0.001 to work better

Comment: When i try a much lower rate, all it seems to do is make all outputs >0.9 and the error total takes much much slower to get to anywhere < 0.5

Comment: I agree with @DennisSoemers; 0.5 is quite high.

Comment: How many epochs are you training over? There's quite a lot of code being shown -- sorry if I missed it.

Comment: 10,000 ...which should be enough right? but 5000 way through, the error gets to 0.2 and stays there (doesnt go beyond)

Comment: Why aren't you using Tensorflow or Theano?

Comment: How do you initialize the weights?

Comment: I am not using tensor flow because i want the challenge - and the weights start as the result of `random.uniform(0,1)`

Comment: @harrylakins What values can the nodes in your input layer take? If they're not in a small range such as [-1, 1] or [0, 1], you'll probably want to normalize them to such a range (for example, divide by maximum value to map it to the [0, 1] range). Also, you'll want to look into implementing the output layer as what's called a ''softmax'' layer. This ensures that your output values always sum up to one, which you want because you want the output to be probabilities. Finally, randomly initializing weights to [-1, 1] may be slightly better than [0, 1], but the difference should be small

Comment: Good question - so by default inputs can be between 0-255 - however, I divide all values by 255 to get a value < 1 for inputting. So, inputs are between 0 and 1. I will try the -1, 1 weight range now! Cheers.

Comment: Okay - so changing the weight ranges to -1,1 made the error output seem completely random - without any positive or negative correlation.

Comment: @harrylakins Yeah ok in your case, when input is typically only positive, I dont expect scaling it to [-1, 1] would help. I still expect using a softmax function as activation function for the output layer to help a lot. If learning initially seems too slow, you can start out with a learning rate of 0.5, but you will want to gradually decrease the value of the learning rate then.

Comment: I have already tried many learning rates :)

Comment: It's completely possible that something outside the neural network went wrong and it's possible that you have multiple errors in and out of your neural network code. For example, you could be messing up the training data processing in addition to having wrong backprop code.

Can you post your entire code?

It would also help me a lot if you post whether the output is correct when you substitute your neural network with a neural network from a well-known library (e.g. Tensorflow, Skflow, Keras).

Comment: I have tested the forward feeding many times manually and it is 100% correct, using the sigmoid `return 1/(1+(math.exp(-value)))` . i have also manually tested the back prop, and it is defiantly working the way described in the tutorial i linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel... 
You may use [pybrain](http://pybrain.org/) module, which provide optimized "Supervised Learning" features like Back-Propagation, R-Prop, etc...
(and have also supervised learning, unsupervised learning, reinforcement learning and black-box optimization algorithm features)

You may find [here](http://connor-johnson.com/2014/04/20/using-pybrain-for-optical-character-recognition-first-whack/) an example of how to use pybrain module to make OCR with a 10×9 inputs array (just adapt to your 28x28 need)

If you definitely would to reinvent the wheel... you may do some introspection of the pybrain source code (because the back prop version of pybrain works) in order to explain/double-check why your code version is not working.

As NN debug is a difficult task, you may also publish more code and share any ressources which are relative to your code ...

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You used in this example one hidden layer. Error backpropagation is capable correct learn one or two hidden layers. In comments you claim the weight initialization from interval 0-1. Once I tried a recognition a paper from picture and obtain miserably results. I have weight init from interval 0-1. When I improve this on -1 to 1 results were excelent.

Ok. Your parameters:
768 15 10

Parameter of deep network doing same task:
768 500 500 2000 10

Error backpropagation is capable doing this task. Try use an two hidden layers with more neurons.

For example, something like this
768 2000 1500 10 :)

And also, you should normalize input from 0-255 to 0-1.

**Update:**
XOR trainig has long duration. Please try 100 000 epochs. If results will be bad, something wrong is in BP implementation. Please initialize weights from -1 to 1 for XOR problem and hidden and output unit must have a bias.

Comment: I have already tried -1,1. Which have even worse results. What do you mean about the hidden layer count and the ability of back prop? Edit answer if you can't comment :)

Comment: In short, Gradient vanishing problem. You compute gradient on output units and then on hidden layers units and than on hidden layer units and than.... and than you have zero error signal and first layers aren't learning anything.

Comment: And maybe. You try classificate a handwriting characters. 768 input units, 15 hidden, 10 output.

Comment: Deep net resolving same task has parameters:
1. 768
2. 500 - first hidden

Comment: Are you saying you do not recommend that structure ?

Comment: Yes, use two hidden layers and much more hidden neurons.

Comment: Will do - and will get back to you - how many neurons on each so you suggest?

Comment: having two hidden layers of 40 neurons each results in an error of 2.24999 and it never improves. It is also dramatically slower (have tried with many different learning rates). Im pretty sure there is something wrong with my actual aglorithm

Comment: Ok, once again. Net trained by better approach using on this classification totally 4 000 hidden units, your net using 80. Yes, more neurons more slow :/

Comment: it takes 30 secs to train one epoch with that many!  How come in the tutorial i linked, they get a 98% success within just minutes from using 784,15,10?

Comment: I don't know. But if you can test your BP algorithm, use your BP on XOR problem. Net parameters can be 2 2 1